# I'm trying to connect AWS RDS to "looker studio", but I keep getting errors... I can connect to tableau and other places

Tags: mysql, amazon-rds, mysql-connector, looker-studio

This will create a public issue which anybody can view and comment on.

Please provide as much information as possible. At least, this should include a description of your issue and steps to reproduce the problem. If possible please provide a summary of what steps or workarounds you have already tried, and any docs or articles you found (un)helpful.

Problem you have encountered:
I'm trying to connect AWS RDS to "looker studio", but I keep getting errors... I can connect to tableau and other places..[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/maJS3.png)

I'm trying to connect AWS RDS to "looker studio", but I keep getting errors... I can connect to tableau and other places...